# BQ E5 HD Telegram half working

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, telegram

I installed Telegram on my BQ E5 HD.
I can start it and connect to my account.

But everything I'm trying after that brings a white page with the waiting / loading pic and then nothing more, even 10 min later.

that problem occurs when I try:

- From de menu:

  1. new group
  2. List item
  3. new private conversation
  4. contacts
- From de parameters page:

  1. change the picture

(well, everything available on the menu)

The application works when a friend contact me first. Then I can send msg & pictures to that friend.
But I can't initiate anything.

Everything is up-to-dated :
Ubuntu 15.04 - armhf (20160123-115651)
Telegram v2.0.4 (0)
(I already had the same problem before the big ubuntu update that occurs 10 days ago)

Do I have to configure something special? Some authorizations somewhere?
I searched but couldn't find anything about that.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Picts showing the problem
-> Problem occurring:
http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1454610565.png

-> when I test these features:
http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1454610712.png

Comment: I have Telegram also and was working fine on my BQ Aquaris E5 HD until yesterday. I get notifications through and then when I click on them to oep the new (or existing) messages, Telegram loads and then closes down. I think there is an issue with the latest update.

Comment: I have version 2.0.8 (2) (several updates since my post) and still have the same problem.. Very annoying

Comment: I had a post open and in it 'ponsky' added this link to the open bug for the issue of Telegram being broken after the update. In it there is a list of steps that I followed. Now I have my Telegram working again. I hope that it helps you too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/telegram-app/+bug/1553279

Comment: @PhilUK Thanks for the info. I hadn't the same problem as my Telegram was woking, but in a very limited way. I followed however the tips in the post and now I can change my picture and import a contact, but still not start a group or a private conversation.. But that's already a nice progress. Your input was much appreciated.

Comment: Hi quenenni, I am glad that the link helped you and that you have made some progress. I will keep an eye out and see if there is anything about that will help you.